# How to animate text back to original starting div place?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The text starting position is on bottom of video. After dragging text anywhere, I want text to come move back to starting position exactly same setting spot. I tried this but it doesn't work the way I want,

```
$("#returnPosition").click(function() {
    $("#subtitle").animate({left:'50',bottom:'40px'});
});
```

but it seems that it only focus on animate to left 50, not included bottom.

Here HTML5 code,

```
<div id="container" class="container">

                <video id="video" width="930" height="500" controls>
                    <source src="caption.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    <source src="caption.ogg" type="video/ogg" >
                    <source src="caption.webm" type="video/webm" >
                </video> 
                <div id="subtitle" class="subtitle">
                </div>
</div>
```

and CSS for subtitle starting position,

```
.container  {
                position:relative;
            }
    .subtitle {
                    position:absolute;
                    width:840px;

                    bottom:40px;
                    left:50;
                    z-index:2000;
                    color:white;

                    font-weight:bold;
                    font-size:150%;
                    text-align:center;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried removing `px`  --  `bottom:'40'`

Comment: @MohammadAdil "px" or just `value` are both valid while inside `""` and inside `Object (:)`

Comment: Does #container have a fixed height?

Comment: @sroes I just added container CSS and it only set relative position.

Comment: And does #video also have position: absolute? That would mean #container doesn't have an height, which in it's turn means you can't position from the bottom.

Comment: @sores, no I do not set #video position: Absolute, only set z-index:0 alone in CSS.

Comment: everytime I click, It only move on to left: 50 and ignored bottom: 40 px.

Comment: Try giving `.container` a known height

Comment: I add height 500 in .container. The result is still the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution and it simple but no animate motion.

```
$("#returnPosition").click(function() {
    $("#subtitle").css({"left": "50", "bottom": "40px"});
    document.getElementById("subtitle").style.top="";
});
```

The reason that subtitle doesn't move to bottom of video is because of top position is set. It need to remove it to make this work. So I clear the top position setting and it work.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting left:50px on the css part and as well on the css that you are running from the javascript.. You are missing the unit of measure.. which you have in px from pixel, but I would strongly suggest to use instead "em".

Comment: You only talked about left position. That the problem. It only move to left and it ignored the bottom set position which it doesn't move to bottom position.

Comment: Further more, please refer to http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/animate it appears that your code is totally different.. Maybe if you click on the examples tab and take a look there for reference won't hurt :)

Answer (score -1):

I would actually use the reference from the link and modify it a bit..

## original:

$("#right").click(function(){
      $(".block").animate({"left": "+=50px"}, "slow");
    });

## your provided code:

$("#returnPosition").click(function() {
    $("#subtitle").animate({left:'50',bottom:'40px'});
});

## my contribution

I used http://pxtoem.com/
to convert your 50px,.. it says 1em, it think it's clearer

```
                        jQuery(function($)
                        {

                    // We clear the event here, the click then we pass it as an argument.. event.. it's the click or the event that triggers the function is the same..     
                // identify the object for easier readyness, because that will allow you to reuse it for a class in the event that you want to extend something later, instead of an id.. this is only in the case that you want to have many divs in the future and it's a normal coding convention, I believe with jQuery.    

                        $("a#returnPosition").off('click').on('click',  function(event) 
                        {

                        // modified this
                        var the_div=$("div#subtitle");
                        the_div.animate({"left": "+=1em"}, 1820);
                        the_div.animate({"bottom": "+=1em"}, 1820);

                        // Keep this in case of the need to return false...    event.preventDefault();
                              });

                        });
```

Comment: again, it only animate to the left. I also want it move to bottom too

Comment: oh god... fix your your example. It not in parse code. Someone else put -1 your answer, not me because I don't have enough reputation for that. :P

Comment: sorry about that... I edited on top of the box and didn't see that needed to take the code away and paste it back for formatting the block.. What you are looking for is a link in the click event, is that assumption correct ?

Comment: Are you trying to achieve something like: http://videojs.com/  ??? Just out of curiosity, you know ;)

Comment: I use your example and the result still the same by only animate to the left. Here my website subtitle video demo, http://www.cs.rit.edu/~rskics/study/caption2/test3.html

Comment: as you can see my demo video, the subtitle was on bottom of video at the start. After dragging subtitle anywhere then click return button from top, the subtitle only move animate to left. It doesn't go where it first came from.

Comment: I have checked your online example, but still don't understand what you are trying to achieve.. First of all, it has ui-draggable as a class but no reference to if you are loading JQuery UI, etc.. which version of jQuery are you currently using ?? Also, I still don't understand in which mode are you talking about.. I have changed the selector and chose 4 lines ; But I don't understand where is the click event supposed to be triggered . ???

Comment: Also, are you casting this on the div#subtitle or on something that appear on firebug as div#scroll.scroll   Is like you are using a javascript for dealing with this, or am I just lost in here... Why not to use something like JScrollpane by Kevin Luck... For dealing with the scrolling text area for the subtitles ? You can find it at: http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/

Comment: You can look at this example:  http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/dynamic_content.html that uses dynamic content... is this what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: ok, the lines option is for caption. If you select 4 lines, the caption will display 4 lines. Same for other option. If I select Transcript 4 lines, then the caption will change into transcript at below video that print 4 lines in whole box. My project is all about manage the caption/transcript with flexible features.